switchable summing audio mixer volume troubles
Consider this audio mixer. There are 3 sources that may play any kind of audio (the sine generators are just illustrative). You can switch any of them to either of 2 outputs using the SPDT switches.
I would like to achieve the same functionality without a perceivable change in volume when one source is switched to the other output. This is especially noticeable if the source in question is silent. Say all of them are switched to output 1. Source 3 is silent and is now switched to output B, causing the overall gain of output 1 to increase. Is there any alternative circuit that would prevent the volume change when switching?


There is. Use the op-amps as inverting summing amplifiers instead of the current passive resistor mixing.

Awesome, thanks a lot!
